# How to expand a list to a certain size without repeating each individual list elements that n-times?

Tags: python, list, loops, repeat

I'm looking to keep the individual elements of a list repeating for x number of times, but can only see how to repeat the full list x number of times.

For example, I want to repeat the list `[3, 5, 1, 9, 8]` such that if `x=12`, then I want to produce tthe following list (i.e the list continues to repeat in order until there are 12 individual elements in the list:

```
[3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5]
```

I can do the below but this is obviously not what I want and I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

```
my_list = [3, 5, 1, 9, 8]
x = 12

print(my_list * 12)
```

```
[3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code repeats list 12 times. You need to repeat list until length is matched. This can achieved using [Itertools - Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

lis = [3, 5, 1, 9, 8]
out = list(islice(cycle(lis), 12))
print(out)
```

Gives #

```
[3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5]
```

More pythonic #

Use a for loop to access each element in list and iterate over 'length' times. Repeat `Ith` element you access through loop in same list until length matches.

```
lis = [3, 5, 1, 9, 8]
length = 12

out = [lis[i%len(lis)] for i in range(length)]
print(out)
```

Gives ##

```
[3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Spot on.  Nice functional way to approach this.  Maybe it's worthy to *elaborate* how it work and include the reference?

Comment: Applolizes Updated..

Comment: No need to apologize.  It's just better to explain how the itertools.*cycle* and *islice* to make it clear.  Thanks. +1   Actually, the first one is much better.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to go about it. If `x` is the final length desired and `lst` is the list (please do not use `list` as a variable name because it overwrites the builtin `list` function), then you can do :

```
lst = (lst * (1 + x // len(lst)))[:x]
```

This multiplies the list by the smallest number needed to get at least N elements, and then it slice the list to keep only the first N. For your example :

```
>>> lst = [3, 5, 1, 9, 8]
>>> x = 12
>>> (lst * (1 + x // len(lst)))[:x]
[3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5, 1, 9, 8, 3, 5]
```

You could also use a loop, for example :

```
index = 0
while len(lst) < x:
    lst.append(lst[index])
    index += 1
```